# R shiny app : shinyanimate::startAnim() inside module not working

Tags: r, shiny, module, shinyanimate

I'm new to the *shinyanimate* package. It works just fine outside modules, but *inside modules* it doesn't work (but no error nor warning).
I'm pretty sure it has something to do with session and ns(), but I can't pinpoint the problem.

Here is my minimum example, with two buttons : the "button" lives in the app, the "button_mod" lives in the module.

```
if (interactive()) {
  mod_test_ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(actionButton(ns("button_mod"), label = "button_mod"))
  }

  mod_test_server <- function(id){
    moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
      ns <- session$ns
      observeEvent(input$button_mod,{
        shinyanimate::startAnim(session, id='button_mod', 'bounce')
      })
      })
  }
  shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
      shinyanimate::withAnim(),
      mod_test_ui("test"),
      actionButton("button", label = "button")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      mod_test_server("test")
      observeEvent(input$button,{
        shinyanimate::startAnim(session, id='button', 'bounce')
      })
    }
  )
}
```

I already tried to pass "session" to the module.

I'm expecting the 2 buttons to have the same behaviour and joyfully bounce when clicked... Anyone has a suggestion ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind I just had an epiphany.
startAnim in a module needs an id like "mymodulename-myid" and not just "myid". Changing the id of the "button_mod" button to "test-button_mod" just does the trick.

New mod_test_server of my minimum example :

```
  mod_test_server <- function(id){
    moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input$button_mod,{
    shinyanimate::startAnim(session, id='test-button_mod', 'bounce')
  })
  })}
```

Anyway... Thanks for the shinyanimate package, and I hope my post would still be useful for struggling beginners !

Comment: Your solution is correct, but it would be better (ie more robust) to use `ns` to construct the required id, rather than hard coding it.

Comment: Ok so I changed to shinyanimate::startAnim(session, id=ns("button_mod"), 'bounce'), it works like a charm. Thanks